# Kamailio cannot connect to remote Mysql Server

Tags: mysql, remote-access, sip

I installed Kamailio 4.0 on a Ubuntu-Server 14.4 and a MySQL Server on another Ubuntu-server using Virtualbox.

> 192.168.0.131: MySQL Server
>
> 192.168.0.141:Kamailio 4.0

I changed the address of database from localhost to 192.168.0.131. But it does not connect.
I googled a lot but could not find the solution.
**What information do you need to help me?**

I have access to server with this command:

```
mysql -h 192.168.0.131 -u kamailio -p
```

Some Outputs:

```
ahmad@ubuntu2:/$ kamctl start

INFO: Starting Kamailio :

ERROR: PID file /var/run/kamailio.pid does not exist -- Kamailio start failed
```

Kamailio Error log

```
ahmad@ubuntu2:/$ kamailio -E -e -dd
loading modules under /usr/local/lib/kamailio/modules_k/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kamailio/modules/
 0(2983) WARNING: <core> [socket_info.c:1407]: fix_hostname(): WARNING: fix_hostname: could not rev. resolve 192.168.0.141
 0(2983) WARNING: <core> [socket_info.c:1407]: fix_hostname(): WARNING: fix_hostname: could not rev. resolve 200.200.200.246
 0(2983) WARNING: <core> [socket_info.c:1407]: fix_hostname(): WARNING: fix_hostname: could not rev. resolve 192.168.0.141
 0(2983) WARNING: <core> [socket_info.c:1407]: fix_hostname(): WARNING: fix_hostname: could not rev. resolve 200.200.200.246
Listening on
             udp: 127.0.0.1:5060
             udp: 192.168.0.141:5060
             udp: 200.200.200.246:5060
             tcp: 127.0.0.1:5060
             tcp: 192.168.0.141:5060
             tcp: 200.200.200.246:5060
Aliases:
             tcp: localhost:5060
             udp: localhost:5060

 0(2983) INFO: <core> [tcp_main.c:4846]: init_tcp(): init_tcp: using epoll_lt as the io watch method (auto detected)
 0(2985) INFO: rr [../outbound/api.h:49]: ob_load_api(): Failed to import bind_ob
 0(2985) INFO: rr [rr_mod.c:159]: mod_init(): outbound module not available
 0(2985) INFO: usrloc [hslot.c:53]: ul_init_locks(): locks array size 512
 0(2985) INFO: auth [auth_mod.c:350]: mod_init(): auth: qop set, but nonce-count (nc_enabled) support disabled
 0(2985) ERROR: db_mysql [km_my_con.c:109]: db_mysql_new_connection(): driver error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.131' (4)
 0(2985) ERROR: <core> [db.c:322]: db_do_init2(): could not add connection to the pool 0(2985) ERROR: usrloc [dlist.c:635]: register_udomain(): failed to open database connection
 0(2985) ERROR: registrar [reg_mod.c:516]: domain_fixup(): failed to register domain
 0(2985) ERROR: <core> [route.c:1215]: fix_actions(): fixing failed (code=-1) at cfg:/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg:637
 0(2985) ERROR: <core> [route.c:1215]: fix_actions(): fixing failed (code=-1) at cfg:/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg:640
 0(2985) ERROR: <core> [route.c:1215]: fix_actions(): fixing failed (code=-1) at cfg:/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg:642
ERROR: error -1 while trying to fix configuration
```

ss output:

```
ahmad@ubuntu2:~$ sudo ss -l | grep mysql
u_str  LISTEN     0      50     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 204079                * 0
tcp    LISTEN     0      50                   *:mysql                 *:*
```

Comment: on the host with `mysql` launch `ss -l | grep mysql` and show output

Comment: Now from the client host: `mysql -h 192.168.0.131 -u username -p`

Comment: ok. I have access to host MySQL using that command

Comment: Then you have properly configured `mysql` and broken `kamailio`.

Comment: Ok. Then how can I test Kamailio?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it

Comment: Should I change my.cfg on server to enabling access from a remote server? bind-address parameter?